# Why do people see movement where none exists?

Tags: optical-illusion

We all know that motion pictures, TV programs and videos aren't necessarily moving and they are different of how we see motion in real life that are just a series of still images in rapid succession on a flat surface, live-action movies are photography and has the same settings as photography like aperture, shutter speed and ISO, has the same functions as photography like motion blur, depth of field and lens flares and also has the same rules as photography, Why do people see ''movement'' in movies, TV broadcasts and videos where none exists?

Comment: Similar to: [Does perception have a "frame rate"?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5531/7001) and [What causes the spokes of a Wagon Wheel to "move"(rotate) in the opposite direction of the Wagon Wheel itself?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15419/7001)